# Pythonic way to filter a list of data with a regex?

Tags: python, regex, list-comprehension

I have a list of strings which I'd like to filter using a regex. I have the beginnings of a solution:

```
lines = ['Some data', 'Data of interest', 'Some data', 'Data of Interest', 'Some data', 'Data of interest']
r = re.compile(r'.*[iI]nterest.*')
relevant_lines = [r.findall(line) for line in lines]
print(relevant_lines)
```

...that almost works:

```
[[], ['Data of interest'], [], ['Data of Interest'], [], ['Data of interest']]
```

...but is there a way to only populate the resulting list with the lines that match and without the nested lists?

**Edit - is there a cleaner way than the following?**

```
[r[0] for r in [r.findall(line) for line in lines] if len(r) > 0]
```

Comment: This is a slightly contrived example of a more complex problem. The regex in question is more complicated - I just wanted a demonstrable example.

Comment: Why don't you just pop the empty lists?

Comment: What do you mean by pop?

Answer (score 2):

Just use a normal loop, not everything is suitable for a list comp:

```
r = re.compile(r'.*[iI]nterest.*')
relevant_lines = []
for line in lines:
    mtch = r.match(line)
    if mtch:
        relevant_lines.append(mtch.group())
```

If you were using a list comp, a generator expression and filtering the empty lists would be better:

```
relevant_lines = filter(None,(r.findall(line) for line in lines))
```

Or indeed filter with match:

```
[x.group() for x in filter(None,(r.match(line) for line in lines))]
```

for python2 use [itertools.ifilter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.ifilter).

Or for a more functional approach switching map for [itertools.imap](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.imap) and filter for `ifilter` using python2:

```
[x.group() for x in filter(None, map(r.match, lines))]
```

Your own list comp can be rewritten using a generator expression for the inner loop:

```
[r[0] for r in (r.findall(line) for line in lines) if r]
```

If you don't need the list use a generator expression and just iterate over it.

Answer (score 2):

```
relevant_lines = [m.group(0) for m in map(r.match, lines) if m is not None]
```

here is result in console:

```
>>> import re
>>> lines = ['Some data', 'Data of interest', 'Some data', 'Data of Interest', 'Some data', 'Data of interest']
>>> r = re.compile(r'.*[iI]nterest.*')
>>> relevant_lines = [m.group(0) for m in map(r.match, lines) if m is not None]
>>> relevant_lines
['Data of interest', 'Data of Interest', 'Data of interest']
```

things are not complicated. it's very good to combine functional programming with generators.